# how to create an html table column with a number of dates in the current month using a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, loops, date, codeigniter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilFft.png]

How do I create a table with a column of the current month's dates in php using a foreach loop?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We really rather expect people to show a bit more effort here, than _just_ asking a plain "how to" question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $m = date('m'); // current month
      $y = date('Y'); // current year

      foreach(range(1, date('t')) as $d) { 
    /* loop through each day in the current month */
        echo '<tr><td class="date">' . $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d . '</td></tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Set the timezone to your preferred timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Get the current month and year
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

// Get the number of days in the current month
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

// Create an array of dates in the current month
$dates = array();
for ($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++) {
$date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
$dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

// Output the dates in an HTML table column
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Dates</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($dates as $date) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$date</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).